# Valgrind showing leaked memory with libobjc

Tags: objective-c, gcc, memory-leaks, libobjc

Trying to track down what I'm missing here.

Running on CentOs5.

I have boiled this down to a simple simple program and still end up with a memory leak. 
Not sure if this is a bug in Valgrind or a bug in libobjc.

main.m

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

and I compile and link it with gcc

```
gcc main.m -o main -lobjc
```

When I run `valgrind main` I get leaked memory

```
==27005== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27005==     in use at exit: 8,485 bytes in 133 blocks
==27005==   total heap usage: 145 allocs, 12 frees, 11,053 bytes allocated
==27005==
==27005== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27005==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==27005==    indirectly lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==27005==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27005==    still reachable: 8,453 bytes in 131 blocks
==27005==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

If I don't link libobjc (leave off the -lobjc) I get no memory leaks.

Ideas?

Comment: What happens if you compile with clang?

Comment: Unfortunately this is on a shared box and I can't get clang installed....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is not libobjc on your centOS? I build and run your code on Mountain Lion ,there is no warnings or errors.

Comment: libobjc is there. I've been writing some objc on the machine and it compiles and runs just fine. Just ran valgrind for grins and ended up stripping everything down to just the main and the only difference is linking libobjc or not

Comment: I suppose the discrepancy between the two OS's could be because of different versions of libobjc or different compiler versions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... so it looks like memory is allocated for each Objective-C class that is declared. So linking libobjc ends up initializing some of these classes at run time whether you're using them or not. The class init cost seems to be a one time cost so I suppose that while memory isn't being released at the end of the program, it really isn't a leak that is going to hurt me because that memory has to be allocated for the entire length of the program anyways.

Still, kinda annoying though. Wish I could release that memory before the app quits.